# WCF Comet Implementation

Tags: wcf, comet

I have a requirement that needs a real-time updates on the Web client (ASP.NET MVC). The only way I can turn around on it is that to implement the **COMET** technique (ServerPush/Reverse-AJAX) technique.

The scenario is that:
**User A** save a message in different website client. Then, **User B** will automatically get the updates made by **User "A"** in different browser.

I actually finish the solution by this Architecture:
     **ASP.NET MVC** - did a jquery ajax (post) request (long-pooled) on the WCF.
     **WCF** - do some polling on the database (SQL Server) with the interval of 1 second. If new data has been added to the database, the polling is break with the data being returned on the client.

WCF COMET Method Pseudo Code:

```
 private Message[] GetMessages(System.Guid userID)
 {
      var messages = new List<Message>();
      var found = false;
      /* declare connection, command */
      while (!found )
      {
           try
           {
                /* open connection - connection.Open(); */
                /* do some database access here */
                /* close connection - connection.Close(); */
                /* if returned record > 0 then process the Message and save to messages variable */
                /* sleep thread : System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); */
                found = true;
           }
           finally
           {
                /* for sure, incase of exception */
                /* close connection - connection.Close(); */
           }
       }
       return messages.ToArray();
 }
```

My concern and question is: **Is it the best approach to do the polling technique in WCF (with 1 second interval)?**

Reason: I maximized the use of database connection pooling and I am expecting that there is no issue on that technique.

**Note:** This is a multi-threaded implementation with the use of WCF given attributes below.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall), ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = true)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using a dedicated realtime server (i.e. don't host the WCF service in IIS) or using a hosted service for realtime updates. As [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548048/anders) says, IIS isn't all that great at handling multiple long-running concurrent requests.

I'd also suggest you look at using a solution which uses [WebSockets](http://pusher.com/websockets) with support for fallback solutions such as Flash, HTTP streaming, HTTP long-polling and then possibly polling. WebSockets are the first standardised method of full duplex bi-directional communication between a client and a server and will ultimately deliver a better solution to any such problems.

For the moment implementing your own Comet/WebSockets realtime solution is definitely going to be a time consuming task (as you may have already found), especially when building a public facing app where it could be accessed by users with a multitude of different browsers.

With this in mind the [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/) project looks very interesting as does the [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) project.

.NET Comet solutions I know of are from [FrozenMountain](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) have a WebSync server for IIS. There is also [PokeIn](http://pokein.com/).

I've compiled a list of [realtime web technologies](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) that may also be useful.

Comment: I actually researched WebSync and I know it is the best COMET service offered for MS Stack. I just avoiding buying 3rd party dll (services) for my website but with these, I think I might need to think it well to buy the WebSync license for Full Duplex communication with the ease of configuration.

Comment: If you are considering 3rd party solutions then We (Pusher) also have a [.NET library](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries#cs) which can easily be integrated into any .NET app (including ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC). There is also a write up on using it [here](http://blog.pusher.com/2011/6/25/the-easiest-way-to-add-real-time-functionality-to-an-asp-net-e-commerce-application). If you want to self-host and you want Comet, and not WebSockets (although I'd recommend WebSockets), then WebSync offer a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

nstead of polling the database cant you have an event sent when updating instead? Thats the way I've implemented Pub/Sub scenarios anyway and it works great.

Comment: By the way, do you have a self hosted WCF service or a IIS hosted one? If its the later you have a problem, IIS has a very low concurrent threads level, 15 or so, after that it will queue the requests, which does not work in a pub/sub scenario.

Comment: Yes, I am a self-hosted WCF service (IIS hosted). I tried to use the SqlDependecy object by enabling the Service Broker service in SQL Server 2008, it works fine and it triggers the data changes back to the client. However, the DBA told me to not use that because there are some limitation on the thread and open-service listeners (maximum limit not defined). Do you have any idea to share with on how to implement proper COMET service?

Comment: Can you share me the exact way of WCF COMET Implementation? Thanks!